# ASP.NET MVC 2: add Bind(Prefix) attribute in ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding

Is it possible to add `BindAttribute` to parameter in action filter?

Each of my view models implements `IViewModel { string Prefix { get; } }` interface and I would like to set `[Bind(Prefix = Model.Prefix)]` for Action parameter automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply attributes at runtime, they are metadata and are baked into the assembly at compile-time, that's the reason you cannot write `[Bind(Prefix = Model.Prefix)]`. `Model.Prefix` needs to be constant and known at compile-time for this to work. Could you describe your scenario in more details, maybe there's another way to achieve your goal.